# Extend built-in User model to support more properties and behaviors in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, loopbackjs

I want a model to represent a profile in my **loopback** app. But, the built-in User model found in loopback only have the following properties

- username
- password
- realm
- emailVerified

What is the best way to extend the `built-in User model` in order to insert more properties like `phone number`, `profile picture`, and the `likes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was better if you have added your code for better answer according to your question but you can check [this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/397) site which talks about customizing the `built-in user model` and also [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html). I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a  new model  common/models/user.json

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
      "firstName"{
         "type":"string",
         "required":true
       }
   }
  "restrictResetPasswordTokenScope": true,
  "emailVerificationRequired": true,
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "accessType": "READ",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Add this to model-config.json

```
  "user":
    "dataSource": "yourDataSource"
  }
```

Hope this works for you