# Registering new users on loopbackjs application

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have already checked this question. But the answer doesn't quite match what I am looking for. [Extend built-in User model to support more properties and behaviors in loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041731/extend-built-in-user-model-to-support-more-properties-and-behaviors-in-loopback?rq=1)

**What I am trying to do:**
Register a new user on my test application. I just need to save the data to mysql database when I click register. Most of the examples on the loopback documentation to register new user, is from a boot script. And the example here does not save it to database - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management. This is more of a problem on why I am not able to save it to database and not so much on the register or user models. But the model userAccount extends from the User base model. So I am not sure if this works differently. I am still not completely familiar with Loopback framework, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Background**
Using loopback 3.0 with NodeJS 8.1.0. Connector used - loopback-connector-mysql connected to MySQL database hosted on Azure.

Using POST /userAccounts (default API endpoint) created by loopback can connect to the database and save user. I am only having trouble with the remote method POST /register.

**Problem**
I get a function not found error. Screenshot - 
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPscB.jpg)

/server/model.config

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "userCredential": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "userIdentity": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "userAccount": {
    "dataSource": "mysqlDB",
    "public": true,
    "options": {
      "remoting": {
        "sharedMethods": {
          "*": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "job": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "jobSeekerProfile": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "userRegister":{
    "dataSource":null,
    "public":false
  }
}
```

/server/models/userAccount.json

```
{
  "name": "userAccount",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {
    "register": {
      "accepts": {
        "arg": "profile",
        "type": "userRegister",
        "description": "User profile details",
        "required": true,
        "http": {
          "source": "body"
        }
      },
      "returns": {
        "arg": "result",
        "type": "object",
        "root": true,
        "description": "This method indicates user registration status."
      },
      "description": "Register new user",
      "http": {
        "verb": "post"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

/server/models/userAccount.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(usersHR) {
  class userAccount {
    async register(userRegister, req, callback) {
      var today = new Date();
      var newUserAccount = new userAccount({
        username: userRegister.username,
        password: userRegister.password,
        joinDate: today.toUTCString(),
        lastLogin: today.toUTCString(),
        realm: 'jobseeker',
        email: userRegister.email,
      });
      userAccount.save(newUserAccount, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('User registered');
        }
      });

      callback(null, 'Registered');
    }
  }

  var cUserAccount = new userAccount(usersHR);

  usersHR.register = function() {
    cUserAccount.register(...arguments);
  };
};
```

/common/models/userRegister.json

```
{
  "name": "userRegister",
  "properties": {
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "description" : "username of user"
    },
    "email":{
      "type":"string",
      "description":"email of user"
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "description" : "password of user"
    },
    "realm":{
      "type":"string",
      "description":"realm of user"
    }
  },
  "hidden": [
    "id"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do: Register a new user on my test application. I
>   just need to save the data to mysql database when I click register.

The default `User` model allows `$everyone` to create a user model.  This means the simplest act of creating a user is to `post` to `/api/Users/create`.

> Most of the examples on the loopback documentation to register new
>   user, is from a boot script. And the example here does not save it to
>   database -
>   https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management.

That is because the connector is the in-memory connector, you can swap in any persistant datasource and the user would persist.

> This
>   is more of a problem on why I am not able to save it to database and
>   not so much on the register or user models. But the model userAccount
>   extends from the User base model. So I am not sure if this works
>   differently. I am still not completely familiar with Loopback
>   framework, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

To solve your error, you're calling the `save` method on `userAccount` (the class you create in the function), you probably want to call it on `usersHR`.

Old:

```
userAccount.save(newUserAccount, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('User registered');
        }
      });
```

New:

```
usersHR.save(newUserAccount, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('User registered');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried both usersHR.save and userAccount.create. Both didn't work. I tried usersHR.create and it worked. 

I'm not sure why though because usersHR.save should automatically create since there is no unique ID. http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-prototype-save

Also, I noticed some other errors in my code. Which I had to fix before this worked.